# Need to Stub a Function that takes a Func<> as a Parameter

Tags: rhino-mocks, stubs

I have a method on my data access layer that can take any function as search criteria and run this against our Entity Framework entities.  I am trying to create unit tests using Rhino Mocks on the business layer, but this calls the DAL method.  When I try to create a stub for this search method, I cannot seem to get it to run correctly.  I have the following method that needs to be stubbed:

```
IQueryable<T> AllSearchBy<T>(params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] search) where T : class;
```

I cannot seem to find a generic expression to use such as `Arg.Is.Anything` for functions, so I tried setting up my own.  I have the following that should return the first value in my _fakeObjs if the Id is 1 and should return a null if the Id is 0 (two separate tests):

```
myObjId = 1;  // or 0 for returning a null
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<MyObj, bool>> myFunc = (a => a.Id == objId); 
IRepository repositoryMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository>();
repositoryMock.Stub(x => x.AllSearchBy<MyObj>(myFunc)).Return(_fakeObjs.Where(x => x.Id == myObjId));
```

However, I am getting the following errors.  For the one that should return an object (value = 1):

```
Message: Test method
NS.MyApp.Test.ObjTest.SearchById_ReturnsObj threw exception:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
```

For the one that should return a null (value = 0):

```
Message: Test method
NS.MyApp.Test.ObjTest.SearchById_ReturnsNull threw exception:
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException:
IRepository.AllSearchBy<NS.EF.MyObj>([]); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

What do I need to do to set up a parameter to pass into the AllSearchBy in my repository?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try to pass following as an argument instead of current `myFunc`:

```
Arg<Expression<Func<MyObj, bool>>[]>.Is.Anything
```